# HTML5 Question - Field Type - trying to change it programatically

Tags: html, mobile

I am working on a Mobile HTML5 Application.

I have a field of `type="number"` then based on another fields value I want to change my Field's type to "text". This changes the on screen keyboard. I am using

```
document.getElementById('daField').type = "text";
```

Sometimes it works other times it stays as number. Its as if I need to shift the focus off of that field and then back.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: This could get really sticky.  You have no control over whether or not the device will change its keyboard or not.  Is there any other approach you can use?  Are you trying to develop it independent of platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById('otherInput').focus();
document.getElementById('daField').type = "text";
document.getElementById('daField').focus();
```

Comment: in this case, wouldn't it be more prudent to use the blur() method?